# Do nearby raids only show silhouettes?

Tags: pokemon-go

The "Evolve" button [shows a silhouette if you don't have the Pokemon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/307293/32055) you'd get from the evolution yet, but shows an image of the Pokemon if you already have it. The nearby raids feature also shows silhouettes; however, it shows silhouettes for Pokemon I already have. Does this feature always only show silhouettes? Will it show the Pokemon if I've completed a raid against that Pokemon before?

This is a screenshot of a Magmar raid; I have caught/hatched/evolved a few Magmars, but never raided one.

[image]

Comment: I've only seen silhouettes so far, even for the Rais Bosses that I've beaten before. Gender doesn't seem to matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a recent update, this has been changed to display the Pokémon rather than the silhouettes based of if you've captured the Pokémon or not.

[image]

Since I have captured Magmar, it shows the Pokémon, but with Raikou uncaptured, it displays the silhouette.

Comment: @Vemonus thanks for the edit. I was on mobile and didn't notice the embarrassing autocorrect

Answer (score 1):

All ongoing Pokemon Raids are depicted in silhouettes. All pending Raids are depicted as an egg. This is shown through this sort of search: [Can you see any full colour Pokemon Raid Bosses? Doesn't look like it.](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=raids%20nearby%20pokemon%20go&source=lnms&tbm=isch&biw=1366&bih=638)  However, this may change in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Raid Bosses are always depicted as silhouettes.

> It's worth pointing out that the datamine of Pokémon Sun & Moon registers regular Pokémon and Totem Pokémon as separate species (for example, Mimikyu and Totem Mimikyu are different Pokémon). It's possible that Pokémon GO may do the same thing; Snorlax and Boss Snorlax may be counted as different Pokémon.

Reference:
[Reddit/r/thesilphroad](https://www.google.de/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/6jn3vd/question_new_raid_silhouette/)

Comment: Can you include the actual link to the reddit sources?

Comment: A link is included now.

Comment: It's not really proving anything if you're comparing Pokémon Go to Pokémon Sun/Moon. They are two separate games made by two separate companies.

Comment: You are right. It is not the best prove for the answer. But from my knowledge so far Niantic adapts the mechanics very close from the classic pokemon games. Like the Combat Points.

Comment: Secondly i catched all raid pokemons before the raid sytem was enabled. Also i see a silhouettes if i click on the nearby raid tap. But my research shows that after catching a pokemon in the bonus challenge, the silhouette will be replaced with a coloured asset from the pokemon.

Comment: Maybe related: the Pokedex does not track santa hat and party hat Pikachu/Raichu separately from regular Pikachu/Raichu (only distinguishe male/female), but the evolution button silhouette does distinguish between the hats (personal observation).

Comment: Not sure the quote in your answer suppose your answer; it seems to suggest that if I have caught raid boss Snorlax, Snorlax won't be a silhouette as raid boss anymore