# Does evolving a Pokémon of different gender grant experience points for new Pokédex entry?

Tags: pokemon-go

When a Pokémon is evolved into a new Pokédex entry, 500 experience points are granted on top of the usual 500 for evolving a Pokémon. Do these points also get awarded for a [different gender evolution of the same Pokémon type](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/307293/why-does-the-evolve-button-sometimes-show-only-a-silhouette/307294#307294), which appears as a silhouette in the evolution button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You only get the bonus 500 experience for the first time you catch or evolve a Pokémon, regardless of gender. You do not get 500 experience for each variant of a particular Pokémon, as they are all part of the same species.

Case in point, I just evolved a Gastly into a Haunter for the first time since the Pokédex update:

[image: haunter pokedex entry]

[image: gastly before evolving]

[image: experience gain]

Comment: Is that your 666 CP Gastly? ;)

Comment: @Kaizerwolf yeah I realized why I was keeping it after I evolved it :(